# Types and generics: difference between `[X <: Int]` and `{type X <: Int }`

Tags: scala, generics, types, existential-type

From what I can tell, these 2 functions are equivalent:

```
def x(xx: X forSome { type X <: Int }): Unit = ()

def y[Y <: Int](yy: Y): Unit = ()
```

According to my observations, nowadays people mostly use second form (that uses `[]`), at the same time I sometimes see articles (mostly old ones, discussing existential types) that use the first one (`forSome`).

What is the reason behind having 2 notations? Is there a pros\cons or things you can\can't do using one or another?

Comment: So as you noticed, it is existential type, the alias is a wildcard in square brackets; pros and cons cannot be described because it is different types; here you can read more: http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/ (with samples), sry for a not compete reply, have no time to write my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are very similar indeed, and you are not alone in the confusion. The best article I've read about existential types gives you a good explanation is indeed [here](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/) (as @DaunnC mentions) . There is actually also a third way to express the same in [Abstract Types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/abstract-types.html).

As reasons go, I would argue that some things are just syntactic sugar and others product of the language's evolution. [Scala 2.14](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/roadmap-next) is scheduled to address some of the redundancy and simplify the language. in particular:

> Simplified and unified type syntax for all forms of information elision: existential types and partial type applications are both expressed with _, forSome syntax is eliminated.